# datatables.net 'formatter` closure function access table column name

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, closures

I'm currently using the very excellent [datatables.net javascript library](https://datatables.net/) to render tables of my database.  Starting with [the server side php script](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) as a starting point, I'm trying to format some of the table columns; I'm using a [formatter](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/formatters) to do some data manipulations, however I need access to the column name within the closure function:

```
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
    return $column_name . $d; // how can I access the column name?
}
```

I've tried using something like

```
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
    $column_name = array_search($d, $row);
    return $column_name . $d; 
}
```

which works fine until two columns exist that have the same $d value.

Furthermore, I've tried something like

```
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
    $column_name = $GLOBALS['Column_name'];
    return $column_name . $d; 
}
```

where $GLOBALS gets set outside of the closure function, within a loop that iterates over the column names; this isn't working however as it seems all column names are being set to the same thing.

Can anyone tell me how to properly do this?